# FF/IE position:absolute bug

Tags: html, css

It seems Chrome is the only browser rendering my code the way I want.

If you notice my `position:absolute` is changing as the border size increases (in FF and IE) however is unaffected in chrome (which is exactly what I want).

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AyCKU/1/) Please try it in chrome/ie/ff to see the difference

The primary purpose of all of this black magic is simple, I need the `.thumb:after` to always be in the center of `.thumb` . If you know a better way let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Fixed -- Checked in FF and Chrome (Don't have newer versions of IE)**

http://jsfiddle.net/AyCKU/8/

Took out margin: 0 auto, just left it at using %'s for top and left and negative margins.

Basically: Used one of the methods for Vertical centering in CSS (Using 50% and negative margins) and applied it to both vertical and horizontal centering.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around a little in Chrome + FF and noticed if you change:

```
.item .thumb:after
```

If you change the positioning to fixed and center it properly it will work in both browsers.

Give it a shot in IE and let me know if it works ..

Comment: Thank's, that's only the case because there's no other items on the page. Try your css in this fiddle instead http://jsfiddle.net/AyCKU/4/